# Should i use the same epochs for each batch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, spacy

i need to understand how the epochs/iterations affect the training of a deep learning model.

I am training a NER model with Spacy 2.1.3, my documents are very long so i cannot train more than 200 documents per iteration. So basically i do

from the document 0 to the document 200 -> 20 epochs

from the document 201 to the document 400 -> 20 epochs

and so on.

Maybe, it is a stupid question but, should the epochs of the next batches be the same as the first 0-200? so if i chose 20 epochs i must train the next with 20 epochs too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`i need to understand how the epochs/iterations affect the training of a deep learning model` - nobody is sure about that one. You may overfit after certain amount of epochs, you should check you accuracy (or other metrics) on validation dataset. Techniques like **Early Stopping** are often employed in order to battle this.

`so i cannot train more than 200 documents per iteration.` - do you mean a batch of examples? If so, it should be smaller (too much information in single iteration and too costly). `32` is usually used for textual data, up to `64`. Batch sizes are often smaller the more epochs you train in order to get into the minimum better (or to escape saddle points).

Furthermore, you should use Python's generators so you can iterate over data of size bigger than your RAM capacity.

Last but not least, each example is usually trained once per epoch. Different approaches (say `oversampling` or `undersampling) are sometimes used but usually when your classes distribution is imbalanced (say 10% examples belong to class`0`and 90% to class`1`) or neural network has problems with specific class (though this one requires more well thought out approach).

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to train each batch with only 1 epoch. Training on the same subset of data for 20 epochs can lead to overfitting which harms your model performance.

To understand better how epochs number trained on each batch affect your performance you can do a grid search and compare the results.